# Sitemap contains urls which are blocked by robots.txt under Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

Really frustrated. It is because of technical errors or Google's cache effect? Do I have to wait for a few days more?

I have been updating my robots file and sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools several times since last night. But each time I resubmit the sitemap, it keeps saying:

```
Sitemap contains urls which are blocked by robots.txt.
```

It seems that all URLs in the sitemap are blocked. Examples:

```
http://janwawa.com/en
http://janwawa.com/en/
http://janwawa.com/en/album
```

This is my robots file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /qsystem/
Disallow: /piwik/
Disallow: /webpublisher/
Disallow: /en/quotation/
Disallow: /th/quotation/
```

This is my sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/hc005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/hk005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/jp005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/kr005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ib005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ib006.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ib010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ij005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/im005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/eu005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/eu010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m010f.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m015.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m015f.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m020.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m025.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m030.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m035.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m040.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m045.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m050.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m055.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m060.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m065.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m070.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/m075.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms015.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms020.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms025.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms030.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms035.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms040.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms045.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/ms050.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/s005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/s010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/hd005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/hd010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/hd015.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/t005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/tour/vn005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/calendar/month.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/heritage.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/visits.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/meals.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/shopping.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/album</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/contact.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/calendar/month.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/start_here.php</loc>
    </url>
        <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/hc005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/hk005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/jp005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/kr005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ib005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ib006.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ib010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ij005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/im005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/eu005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/eu010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m010f.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m015.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m015f.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m020.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m025.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m030.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m035.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m040.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m045.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m050.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m055.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m060.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m065.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m070.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/m075.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms015.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms020.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms025.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms030.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms035.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms040.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms045.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/ms050.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/s005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/s010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/hd005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/hd010.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/hd015.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/t005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/tour/vn005.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/calendar/month.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/heritage.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/visits.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/meals.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/shopping.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/album</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/contact.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/calendar/month.php</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/start_here.php</loc>
    </url>

<url>
    <loc>http://janwawa.com/en/</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="th"
                 href="http://janwawa.com/th/"
                 />
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://janwawa.com/en/"
                 />
</url>

<url>
    <loc>http://janwawa.com/th/</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="en"
                 href="http://janwawa.com/en/"
                 />
     <xhtml:link 
                 rel="alternate"
                 hreflang="th"
                 href="http://janwawa.com/th/"
                 />
</url>

</urlset>
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay , i have been to your site once , looked your sitemap as well robots.txt , you are seems doing right but the problem is google webmaster tool .
Here is some tips you should try and let me know if you are able to figure out or not ,
go to your Webmaster dashborad -> select the site -> Fetch as Google -> then put any URL in belongs to your site directory which wanted to let Google crawl , then submit for index , if Google has not found any error then your problem would be solved by doing below method 
Again go to the fetch as Google and then enter h ttp://janwawa.com/en and submit for index with the option of CRAWL DIRECT URL AND LINK .

okay let me know if you found any problems .

Comment: Thanks for helping. I can now see the warning message is gone and Google has started indexing. I submitted 118 links and it indexed 17 and stopped there the last two days. I hope it will continue indexing soon.

Comment: This shows that there will be at least a few hours' delay before the newly uploaded robots.txt is effective.